# Call different footer.phtml file for homepage

Tags: magento-1.9

How can I call `footer.phtml` only for magento homepage, for rest of the site call `footer1.phtml` file.
I am using `magento version:1.9`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the footer.phtml template, do the if-else.
**Put his check on the homepage.**

Here is a quick Magento code to check if the current page is homepage or not.

If you are in template/page/html/header.phtml template file, then you can check for homepage with the following code:

```
if($this->getIsHomePage()) {
        echo 'You are in Homepage!';
    } else {
        echo 'You are NOT in Homepage!';
    }
```

If you are elsewhere (in any other .phtml template file or in any other .php class file) then you can use the following code:

```
if(Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage()) {
    echo 'You are in Homepage!';
} else {
    echo 'You are NOT in Homepage!';
}
```

Below is an alternative way to check for homepage:-

```
$routeName = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName(); 
$identifier = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();

if($routeName == 'cms' && $identifier == 'home') {
    echo 'You are in Homepage!';
} else {
    echo 'You are NOT in Homepage!';
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. code works in the local but on the server code didn't work

Comment: your answer is correct bro.. but some how server's may issue i think

Answer (score 1):

You could potentialy do something via the Design tab in CMS > Pages

```
<reference name="root">
    <remove name="footer" />
    <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer-home" as="footer" template="page/html/footer-home.phtml">
</reference>
```

Comment: I used your code but not works ... any need to do something extra like in layout file..

Comment: use `as="footer"` instead of  `as="footer-home"` now its works fine +1 from me

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is checking class in body tag, then having the footer1 and footer content in the same template.

Homepage will have class "cms-index-index", based on that you can determine where are you and show/hide content with css. IMO, it may be easier, so you don't need to have logic to check the router which basically is there in body tag.

```
.cms-index-index .footer-content {
    display: block;
}

.cms-index-index .footer1-content, 
.footer-content {
    display: none;
}
```